# Refresh more complete than with Ctrl-F5 or Ctrl-Shift-R

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, reloadevery

I have a html-page (1) which in turn is filled with another html-document (2) by a js-file (3). I use Firefox.

I have modified a href-attribute inside (2), but when I reload (1) with Ctrl-F5, the modification is not there, the old version is there. I even tried removing (2) from the server, the content was still displayed and used the old version of the href-attribute.

Is there yet an even more complete way to bypass cache not only for (1) and (3) but also for (2)?

Comment: Interesting.  I, also, would think Ctrl-F5 would take care of it.  As a test, have you cleared the browser's cache to make sure it's really doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: Yes I tried clearing the cache. That seemed to work (although it's a nusance), until now.

Comment: Sry for the non-informative comment 14hrs ago. I kept collecting loginfo to continue it and after a very long time I was able to figure out that the problem was not related to firefox this time. I forgot to cancel the comment, somehow i must have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+F5 forces a reload of the current page, but not necessarily guarantee other resources referenced by the page are fetched again. Therefore, your subresource is likely still cached. There are a few ways to deal with that.

The simplest is to clear your browser's cache entirely by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Delete and configuring what you want to delete in the dialog that opens.

If the sub-referenced content is changing often, you could configure your web server to serve it with [`pragma:no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma) and similar techniques to hint to Firefox that the content should always be fetched fresh.

If you are unfamiliar with web server configuration, another way is to reference your
sub-resource with some random number appended to the end of the query-string (for example, subpage.html?8723654). This way, the number can be changed whenever you wish (or every time, if you use JavaScript) so every request to subpage.html looks like a different URL, as far as the browser is concerned.

I've only touched on each one of these solutions very briefly. Let me know if you want more details on any one of them.

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you, I'll get back to this when the issue arises again; at the moment I'm working on something completely different.